# Two select dropdowns list - the second dropdown output will depend on the selected first select dropdown list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, compare, javascript-objects

I'm using reactJS and I have here the choices for two select dropdown list names **categories** and **items**

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
    this.state = {
      categories: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "category_name": "Powertools"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "category_name": "Consumables"
        }
      ],
      items: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "item_name": "Grinder",
          "category_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "item_name": "Drill",
          "category_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "item_name": "Welding rod",
          "category_id": 2
        },
      ],
    };
  }
```

I'm trying to output the items dropdown list choices depending on the selected value of the categories dropdown list.

For example:

**Dropdown 1 Selected Value:** Powertools

**Dropdown 2 choices:** Grinder, Drill

Another example:

**Dropdown 1 Selected Value:** Consumables

**Dropdown 2 choices:** Welding rod

As of now, I've found [this code snippet](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-test-selected-value-jc52f?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/TestDeleteByKey.js) that does the thing that I want. Unfortunately, it's in a function component and I'm trying to convert it to a class component but with no success.

Comment: Let me explain what is to be done and you can code later. On change of 1st select, get the value and use it to filter items. Use this items as data source for second select

Comment: Thank you, sir. I've also reached that point. I can console.log the item names, but I'm wondering because the dropdown box for items doesn't show the new choices.

Comment: Are yo saving filtered items in state or local variable?

Comment: In a state sir. I'll recreate my code and I will update you once done sir.

Comment: Oh, I just fixed my problem sir upon recreating it. How awkward. :D I'll just post the answer here. Thank you for the guidance sir @Rajesh I think it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

I was guided by Sir. Rajesh and I were able to solve the problem.

Here's the code

```
import { Component } from 'react';

class Testing2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      categories: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "category_name": "Powertools"
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "category_name": "Consumables"
        }
      ],
      items: [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "item_name": "Grinder",
          "category_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "item_name": "Drill",
          "category_id": 1
        },
        {
          "id": 3,
          "item_name": "Welding rod",
          "category_id": 2
        },
      ],
      form_transactions: [],
      filteredItems: []
    };
  }


  handleChange_transactions = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    let form = this.state.form_transactions;
    form[name] = value;
    this.setState({ form });

    const state_filteredItemNames = this.state.items.filter(element => element.category_id == value);
    this.setState({ filteredItems: state_filteredItemNames });
  }

  render() {

    //list categories
    const list_categories = this.state.categories.map(data =>
      <option
        value={data.id}
        key={data.id}
      >
        {data.category_name}
      </option>
    )

    const list_items = this.state.filteredItems.map(data =>
      <option
        value={data.id}
        key={data.id}
      >
        {data.item_name}
      </option>
    )

    return (
      <>
        <form>
          <div>
            <select onChange={this.handleChange_transactions}>
              {list_categories}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <select>
              {list_items}
            </select>
          </div >
        </form >
      </>
    )
  }
}

export default Testing2;
```

**Output:**

[image]